# Wordlist generator that support BigIntegers for Huge Numbers

Tags: java, list, biginteger, word-list

I need a help to complete a program that will generate a wordlist from chosen characters and length (it need to support a big length).

At first you need to fix this both by adding the length (wordlength) wanted and making a string of the specified characters(alphabet).

So the full number of words is:

```
long MAX_WORDS = (long) Math.pow(alphabet.length(), wordlength);
```

Actually, I made it and it work (for the example of short word of 2 or 66 characters).

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class wordlistgenenreg {

public static void main(String[] args) { 
generate(); 
}

private static void generate(){
int wordlength =2;
String alphabet = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.-_~";
final long MAX_WORDS = (long) Math.pow(alphabet.length(), wordlength);
final int RADIX = alphabet.length();

for (long i = 0; i < MAX_WORDS; i++) {
    int[] indices = convertToRadix(RADIX, i, wordlength);
    char[] word = new char[wordlength];
    for (int k = 0; k < wordlength; k++) {word[k] = alphabet.charAt(indices[k]);}
    String fullword=new String(word);
    System.out.println(fullword);
}

System.out.println("completed!");
}

private static int[] convertToRadix(int radix, long number, int wordlength) {
int[] indices = new int[wordlength];
for (int i = wordlength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (number > 0) {
        int rest = (int) (number % radix);
        number /= radix;
        indices[i] = rest;
    } else {
        indices[i] = 0;
    }

}
return indices;
}
}
```

but there are a problem when i want to generate a really big string of 64 characters from 66. Because:

> MAX_WORDS = 66^64 = 282365657377235405270307754780751252031361330095689004197961218014051357270480550051149871489969454245263206971867136

So I tried to change it to make it work with the `BigInteger`. But us a result, I always obtain the String:

> "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

So there are a problem that i didn't figure it out. This my work on changing it:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class wordlistgen {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    generate();
}

private static void generate() {
int wordlength = 64;
String alphabet = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.-_~";
BigInteger max_words=new BigInteger("282365657377235405270307754780751252031361330095689004197961218014051357270480550051149871489969454245263206971867136");
final int RADIX = alphabet.length(); 
BigInteger plus=BigInteger.valueOf(1);

for (BigInteger i = new BigInteger("0"); i.compareTo(max_words) <0; i.add(plus)) {
    int[] indices = convertToRadix(RADIX, i, wordlength);
    char[] word = new char[wordlength];
    for (int k = 0; k < wordlength; k++) {word[k] = alphabet.charAt(indices[k]);}
    String fullword=new String(word);
    System.out.println(fullword);        
}
}

private static int[] convertToRadix(int radix, BigInteger i2, int wordlength) {
BigInteger zero=BigInteger.valueOf(0);
BigInteger big_radix=BigInteger.valueOf(radix);
int[] indices = new int[wordlength];
for (int i = wordlength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (i2.compareTo(zero)==0) {

        BigInteger rest =i2.remainder(big_radix);
        BigInteger ab=i2.divide(big_radix);
        i2=ab;
        indices[i] = rest.intValue();
    } else {
        indices[i] = 0;
    }
}
return indices;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the `if` from your original version:

```
if (number > 0) {
    int rest = (int) (number % radix);
    number /= radix;
    indices[i] = rest;
} else {
    indices[i] = 0;
}
```

And the same `if` in the `BigInteger` version:

```
if (i2.compareTo(zero)==0) {

    BigInteger rest =i2.remainder(big_radix);
    BigInteger ab=i2.divide(big_radix);
    i2=ab;
    indices[i] = rest.intValue();
} else {
    indices[i] = 0;
}
```

As you can see, in your new `if`, you are asking if `number == 0` instead of `number > 0`. So you always end up in the `else`.

As a side note: you are running a loop from 0 to your `max_words`. If each iteration takes merely a nanosecond to complete, it will still take 368788667672120349090672500612638816231217766896306723928560063188563281831044121479026746095987887263264265 years. Enough time for the universe to disintegrate into full entropy. I'd suggest re-thinking your algorithm.

Comment: even making it >=0 it still the same problem. i know it will take a long time, but i think it's just month not more. and can you please help me to correct it? i really need to do that.

Comment: No, it's a lot more than a month, the number I gave is the result of a calculation I did. It's in years. Many, many years. I can't help you with your algorithm because your question does not have the full information about this assignment and I suspect that you have misinterpreted it.